# Call Azure API from WebJob/ Shared code between WebJob and web API

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, webapi, azure-webjobs-continuous

I have a web API in an ASE and an associated web job. I am trying to call this web API from the web job but it always fails with:

> winhttpexception: a security error has occurred.

I have put in all the tls related settings but still getting the error.
Any suggestions on the error?
Also is there a way to share code between WebJob and web API?

Comment: Have you checked your NSG?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/network-info

Comment: Both are in the same ase and I am able to access the web api using tcpping from kudu console.

Comment: Yes, you could also try my method to call webapi, it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  was able to resolve the issue by  setting the below in my code.This resolved the Security Error.

```
using(var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
   ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender,certificate,chain,sslPolicyErrors) => true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a console app and publish it as Azure WebJobs. For username and password you could click `Get Publish Profile` in your Azure webapp overview to get them.
[image]

Then you could use the following code in Console App to call your Azure Webapi.

```
string userName = "$xxxxxx";
string userPassword = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
string webAppName = "xxxxxx";
var base64Auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes($"{userName}:{userPassword}"));
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Auth);
    var baseUrl = new Uri($"https://{webAppName}.azurewebsites.net/api/values");
    var result = client.GetAsync(baseUrl).Result;
    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        readTask.Wait();
        var value = readTask.Result;
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("run successfully");
```

Output as below:
[image]